# how to test json to routes and controller in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a controller set up to handle a json request in the routes.db. How do I test if it works in rails console?

Here is my routes.

```
post '/requests', to: 'requests#create', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

Controller

```
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

def create
if @object.save
  render json: { success: t(:success_message) }, status: :ok
else
  render json: { errors: @object.errors.joins(', ') }, status: :unprocessab$
end
```

end
end

Answer (score 2):

May doing something like this in rails console?

```
>> app.post "/requests"
```

If you get an object returned then save the above to a variable and see its contents

Hope it helps!

Comment: Got an error message.

[6] pry(main)> app.post "requests"
    URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): 
    http://www.requests.com:80requests
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-
    2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/uri/rfc3986_parser.rb:67:in `split'

Comment: can you see if you need to append / before like '/requests'

Comment: Processing by RequestsController#create as JSON
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms


  
NoMethodError (undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass):
  
app/controllers/requests_controller.rb:4:in `create

Comment: yeah, does that mean i need to post an object in rails console?

Comment: Where are you getting @object from in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I use the Advanced Rest Client (ARC) Chrome plugin: https://advancedrestclient.com/

Then just starts yours rails server (`rails s`) and pop in your route to ARC (i.e. `localhost:3000/requests`). With ARC you can choose to GET, POST, PUT and more! You can even add params to your post which it sounds like you will need in your case.

Then in either the console, watch what's happening with the rails server or see what json output that is returned in ARC.